# Text input delay

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to realise a text delay input in Excel.

User need to get some data from stream scanner.
If user is scanning again in 3 seconds, Excel need to clear current cell and do not move cursor on next cell.

**This is my code:**

```
Public oldtime As Date
Public nowtime As Date
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
nowtime = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If (nowtime - oldtime) > 0.0003 Then
        oldtime = Now
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that it doesn't work normally. Some times it is clearing cell, but mostly of all - not.
Please, could you help me?

Comment: Sorry but I'm lost :) Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay, look. Stream scanner is connected to PC as USB keyboard. User is scanning barcode. Scanner types input data in Excel. I need to prevent data input and excel cursor move on next cell if time between last input and now is less than 3 seconds.

Comment: Excel stopps on string `ActiveCell.Value = ""` with error Method 'Value' of object Range failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to test with the scanner but try this:

```
Option Explicit
Public oldtime As Variant
'Public nowtime As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Timer - oldtime) > 3 Then
        oldtime = Timer
    Else
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this what your're trying?

Comment: This doesnt work, you will receive error (Method 'Value' of object Range failed) on Target.Value=""

Comment: Why is that? It is working fine in my system. Would you mind re-starting your XL?

Comment: Please, take a look on this screenshots.[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img842/6025/ukay.jpg) and 
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img842/7803/b820.jpg)

Comment: Really strange. Try this then `Target.ClearContents`. But I'm really surprised `Target.Value = ""` doesn't work. Btw, your target cell is an ordinary cell? no validation, or not merge? And you are selecting only one cell?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Except of `Target.Value=""` we need to use `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Clear`